# Stream multiple files with a single request using python requests

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I'm using python's requests library to upload images into a server created by django / drf. It is a simple task and test script looks like this:

```
files = {
    'client_files[0]': ('415.png', open('E:\\Olaylar\\test_set\\cvat_test_small\\415.png', 'rb')),
    'client_files[1]': ('422.png', open('E:\\Olaylar\\test_set\\cvat_test_small\\422.png', 'rb')),
    'client_files[2]': ('485.png', open('E:\\Olaylar\\test_set\\cvat_test_small\\485.png', 'rb'))
}

payload = {
    'image_quality': 50
}

response = requests.post(post_url, auth=auth, data=payload,files=files)
```

The problem is, I need to upload hundreds, if not thousands of images, and in a single request. So when I try to read all files into memory in order to post them, I run out of memory quite fast.

I know there is a possible solution, by putting a generator in data argument of post method, and streaming the data by chunks. That would solve my problem quite well, but requests library does not support that functionality in files argument of the post method too.

I will be grateful for any help or advice how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not loop over each file and upload one at a time?

Comment: Well, I use this to create annotation tasks in an annotation tool called CVAT, and it's api assumes every post request is another task. So if I split it to chunks and upload each chunk with a new post request, it also splits my data to different tasks (while that image sets are supposed to be a single task)